# Unable to execute protractor, getting "Could not find update-config.json" error message

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

When I'm trying to execute my `<configuration>.js` file, I'm getting the error below:

```
[14:49:13] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:49:13] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[14:49:13] E/direct - Error code: 135
[14:49:13] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[14:49:13] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
```

I ran the command `webdriver-manager update` and tried to execute the file, but the same error persists. Can anyone help me to overcome the same?

Comment: Are you using `directConnect`, or do you have a local `webdriver-manager` installed?

Comment: I'm using the dirctconnect (**directConnect: true**).

Comment: Did you run a `webdriver-manager update` before running?

Comment: Yes I have run the comment. I'm using the corporate proxy so I execute the comment as **webdriver-manager update --proxy=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx**

Answer (score 60):

Using `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` worked for me.

Comment: In case anyone's new to node like me its 
`node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

Comment: Thank you! I was able to run e2e on GitHub with this step.
`run: node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

Comment: I added --gecko=false

Answer (score 17):

`directConnect` does not use the global installed version but the version that is provided by Protractor in `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/`. You will need to update that one.

If you have a global version installed the command `webdriver-manager update` will update the global installed webdriver-manager. If you have a global installed version please remove it, or don't use the `directConnect` and adjust you protractor config with `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/'`

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked for me. I set directConnect to false, added seleniumAddress and ran webdriver-manager start

Comment: fwiw my local webdriver manager was here node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run: `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` you can also write a script in package.json. For example: `"e2e:update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update --gecko false"`

Calling it with `npm run e2e:update-wedriver` solved the error in my case.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in VSCode after I upgraded to angular-cli v6.0.8. Trying to change the protractor.conf file to use directConnect: false and add a seleniumAddress didn't work for me.

However, I was able to fix this by simply stopping any running server (or lite server instances), restart VSCode, and restart the servers. I'm now able to run protractor 5.3.0 with @angular/cli 6.0.8 while still using directConnect: true.